# Asus Zenbook UX31A touchpad driver no longer works in Windows 10

Tags: touchpad, asus-laptop, zenbook

As the title says, I upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 10 and now the multitouch no longer works. The Asus website doesn't appear to have drivers for Windows 8 or 10 (although the Windows 7 drivers worked for Windows 8.) No such luck for Windows 10.

Anybody have any luck with this? It's driving me crazy.

EDIT:

To the person who suggested this question was a duplicate - this laptop does not use a synaptic touchpad. When I try to install the drivers for the synaptic touchpad I get an error "Synaptic device not found."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 10 on asus x44h touchpad scolling not working](http://superuser.com/questions/947914/windows-10-on-asus-x44h-touchpad-scolling-not-working)

Comment: @DavidPostill nope. I have a different touchpad driver. See my edits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, and here's what seems to have solved the problem.

First, I went into the Control Panel (It's in File Explorer from the Start Menu), and I went into Programs and then Uninstall Programs. I scrolled down to the Elan Touchpad program, and when I right-clicked, it allowed me to update the program.

Second, I uninstalled the Asus Smart Gesture program. I downloaded the update for the driver from here: http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=smart+gesture (choose the Windows 10 version), and I installed the update.

As far as I can tell, this has restored the touchpad, and I can use smart gestures to scroll and change the magnification.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The given URL is no longer found. There's http://web.archive.org/web/20140705135548/http://support.asus.com:80/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=smart+gesture but the operating system selection menu, in that capture of the page, does not work. http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/ASUS-ZenBook-UX31A/HelpDesk_Download/ may offer what's required.

Comment: Try this url: https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1009613 it has a link to download Asus Smart Gesture towards the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with the touchpad too since I upgraded to win10.
Contacted Asus support and was told ux31a is not and will not be a win10 compatible device. They recommended not to update to win10...

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling the gesture/touchpad software for Windows 8 from the website. That seemed to work fr me.

Comment: ditto, worked fine for me too with Windows 10 using Mark above's link