# Windows 10 -no mouse

Tags: windows-10

I see many people are having issues with no laptop mouse after upgrade. I see the many suggestions - but how am I to do any of them if my mouse doesn't work?! I can't do anything

Comment: What about USB mouse? Even without mouse, you can still update your mouse driver.

Comment: Use the keyboard and install the appropriate touchpad/mouse software/drivers. See [Windows 10 on asus x44h touchpad scolling not working](http://superuser.com/q/947914)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use Mouse Keys to move the mouse pointer?

Full details on [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Use-Mouse-Keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer)

Comment: They still have to use the mouse to activate mouse keys.